# C# Console Application uses command line, command does not execute

Tags: c#, command-line, amazon-s3, console-application, command-line-interface

I'm using a console application and C# to execute some AWS (S3) CLI commands.  I thought I had it working, because most of the commands execute just fine.  But the last command is `sync`, and it doesn't work.  But I know the command itself is correct, because a copy-paste into a command line window works just fine.  Below is what I have so far:

```
String commands = "echo echo & echo echo"; 
commands += " & aws s3 ls s3://bbbbbb";
commands += " & aws s3 sync C:\test\test2 s3://bbbbbb"; //this is the line that doesn't execute
//make this to use with a Process
ProcessStartInfo commandsToRun = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/c " + commands);
//make the Process and run it
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = commandsToRun;
process.Start();
```

I don't have any errors or any clues as to what's going on, I just don't get output from the last command, and if I check with `ls` or a Cloudberry Explorer, I can see that nothing has happened.  Can anybody tell me what's going on here?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the working directory of the command matter?

Comment: Is just one command, or several?  Do you need to insert some newlines?

Comment: The working directory shouldn't matter, since the pathnames given are absolute.

Comment: it's several, but I don't know that I need newlines.  both `echo` commands and the `ls` work just fine without them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your example is what you really use, I would blame C# string escaping. `"\t"` in your path will translate as horizontal tab. Use verbatim string (like you do in the `ProcessStartInfo`)

```
commands += @" & aws s3 sync C:\test\test2 s3://bbbbbb";
```

Or escape the backslashes

```
commands += " & aws s3 sync C:\\test\\test2 s3://bbbbbb";
```

Comment: Oh!  I never thought about string escaping.  That is what I'm really using, so the `@` fixed the problem.  Thank you!